# How many $n$-digit numbers are there with no or even number of $1$s in them if only digits $1$, $2$, $3$ and $4$ are allowed?

Tags: permutations, combinations, binomial-theorem

You are given an unlimited supply of each of the digits 1,2,3 or 4. Using only these four digits, you construct n digit numbers. Such n digit numbers will be called LEGITIMATE if it contains the digit 1 either an even number times or not at all. Number of n digit legitimate numbers are:-
My attempt:-
(1) if no 1 is present - $3^n$
(2) if 1 present 2times-${n\choose 2}.3^{n-2}$
(3)if 1 present 4times-${n\choose 4}.3^{n-4}$
And so on...
Hence, $3^n+3^{n-2}{n\choose2}+$...
Therefore $\frac{(3+1)^n}{2} =2^{2n-1}$ but the real ans is
$2^{n-1}(2^n+1)$, please tell complete solution.

Comment: "*an even number of times or not at all*"  Zero is even... this clarification was redundant.

Comment: "*Therefore $\frac{(3+1)^n}{2}$...*"  I don't follow where this came from.  Just because you have half of the terms in a sum doesn't necessarily mean the total sum is half of the original.  $2+4+6$ has half of the terms in the sum as $1+2+3+4+5+6$ yet is not half of the total sum.  How do you justify this step?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be making what is often called a *silly mistake*.

Starting from the second term, every other term is missing from the series, compared to a usual binomial expansion. You didn't account for that.

$$\begin{align*}
&3^n + 3^{n-2} \binom{n}{2} + 3^{n-4} \binom{n}{4} + \cdots \\[0.3cm]
=\;&\frac{(3+1)^n + (3 - 1)^n}{2} \\[0.3cm]
=\;& \frac{4^n + 2^n}{2} \\[0.3cm]
=\;& 2^{n-1}(2^n + 1)
\end{align*}$$

As pointed out by JMoravitz in the comments below, the last term in the series above would either be $3 \binom{n}{n-1}$ or $\binom{n}{n}$ depending on whether $n$ is even or odd.

Comment: Given that each of the terms in the surviving sum have binomial coefficients where the bottom number is even, surely only one of $3\binom{n}{n-1}$ or $\binom{n}{n}$ are used, but not both, and which is used is dependent on the parity of $n$.  Might want to replace that final $+$ with an "or" or something similar

Comment: You can get a vertically centred ellipsis with proper spacing to surrounding binary operators like $+$ using `\cdots`.

Comment: You made what is often called a *sign error*. The two $-$ signs in the intermediate lines should be $+$ signs to match the first and last lines. Also, in the last line, $n$ should be in the exponent.

Comment: @JMoravitz thank you for correcting me.

Comment: @joriki thank you for correcting me and for the LaTeX tip. Also, I see you have a sense of humor.

Comment: I hope I do :-). It wasn't a $\LaTeX$ tip; I meant that where it says $2n$ in the last line of the displayed equation it should say $2^n$ instead.

Comment: Fixed..the \cdots tip though